# Set NSDateFormatter to HeaderSection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, nsdateformatter

I have tried to add the timer to the **UINavigationTabBar** using **viewForHeaderInSection:**.
But it is not display the time.if i try the same in -(void)viewDidLoad method it is working. what is wrong in my code.whether it is possibel to call the NSDateFormatter in NavigationTabBar? Here is the code

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
   UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
   label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
   NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
   label1.text=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
   [self performSelector:@selector(timeLimiteAlert) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
   [view addSubview:label1];
   [label1 release];
   return [view autorelease];
}
```

Comment: The ViewForHeaderInsection delegate method is only for setting custom section headers in tableviews. Please explain better what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the view to the NavigationBar:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
```

So the code would be like:

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss"];
label1.text=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
[self performSelector:@selector(timeLimiteAlert) withObject:self afterDelay:1.0];
[view addSubview:label1];
self.navigationItem.titleView = view;
```

And put it in ViewDidLoad. ;)

Comment: Before u already write this code in your question, why u tell me I forgot self.navigationItem.titleView = view;

Comment: Please give this answer a +1 if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set it at viewDidLoad:

```
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
 UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
 label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
```

Hope it works.